# How to call a x64 C++ dll from VB6 (x86)?

Tags: c++, vb6

I'm trying to call a x64 C++ function (in .dll) from VB6 application.
Warning message displayed be below:

> "Run-time error '48'/File not found ***.dll"

Is there any way to do this calling?

*Note: x86 C++ .dll is working normal And my x64 C++ .dll is too big and cannot change to x86 complier.*

Comment: You cannot use an x64 native library from VB6.

Comment: Is the 64-bit DLL exposing COM components? Or is it just exported functions? If the latter to use the DLLSurrogate method noted in the answer below you would have to create a 64 bit COM wrapper DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try with [DllSurrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/dllsurrogate).
Take a look at [Calling 64 bit code from a 32 bit VB6 application](https://www.mobilize.net/blog/call-64-bits-code-from-a-32bit-vb6-app).

Comment: This is example for C# IDE. I think it has two reasons that cannot apply this example:
1. C++ IDE doesn't have the "Register for COM interop" option. 
2. I think My VB6 application just only run on specific machine which configure DllSurrogate. How to run it on another machine?